# Right align text in string containing newlines

Tags: python, string

Say I have a string in Python with newline characters:

```
my_string='{a}\n{b}\n{c}'.format(a=a,b=b,c=c)
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` hold strings of possibly different length.

How can I right adjust the lines of `my_string`?

Comment: You can't adjust it *within*. This time I'm sure you'll need to create a new `str` object.

Comment: Thanks @frostnational I updated the post to clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there's no built in function to right align mulitiple lines, but it looks like a piece of cake:

```
a = """
Lorem 
ipsum dolor sit 
amet, consectetur adipisicing 
elit
"""

lines = a.strip().splitlines()
width = max(map(len, lines))
print '\n'.join(x.rjust(width, '*') for x in lines)
```

(`*` is for clarity only, remove it when you're ready testing).

Alternatively, if you know in advance how wide the text is going to be, you can specify the alignment in the format string:

```
mystring = '{a:>20}\n{b:>20}\n{c:>20}'.format(a=a,b=b,c=c)
```